# COM interop interface casting

Tags: .net, com-interop, com-interface

Following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736.aspx), I have successfully translated C++ COM class/interface declaration into C# like this:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid(IfaceGuid)]
public interface IFoo
{
  void Bar();
}

[ComImport, Guid(ClassGuid)]
public class Foo
{ }
```

I use it like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var ifoo = (IFoo)foo;

ifoo.Bar();
```

My question is, how can this possibly work, considering that `Foo` doesn't implement `IFoo` (even at runtime, `typeof(Foo).GetInterfaces()` is empty) and that user-defined conversions to interfaces are forbidden?

Is this some special handling reserved just for COM? What does the C# specification have to say about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComImport` types are treated differently compared to "normal" .NET classes, as they constitute a runtime-callable wrapper around an underlying COM coclass. Casting an instance of one of these into a COM interface type is transparently mapped into a call to the object's implementation of the COM interface method `IUnknown.QueryInterface`.

If QI for the requested interface succeeds at the COM level, then the C# cast will also succeed.

Comment: If you want to know more on the subject there is a book from Adam NATHAN **.NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide** which explains that in details.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, casts for classes marked with `ComImport` to COM interfaces result in a `QueryInterface()` under the hood - that I guess is done inside the RCW.

This way `new` leads to `CoCreateInstance()` being called and then the cast leads to `QueryInterface()` being called.